# Adding identical element to several children in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

Background: I am trying to flesh out an XML report with metadata that I retrieve from a web service endpoint. The report lists text modules and graphics, and each graphic has several resolutions. I am not able to add the metadata for each resolution.

Issue: Here is the problem simplified.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

myxml = """\
<report>
    <object id="foo">
        <reportitems>
            <reportitem id="1"/>
            <reportitem id="2"/>
            <reportitem id="3"/>
        </reportitems>
    </object>
</report>
"""

report = ET.fromstring(myxml)
test = ET.Element("test", foo="bar")

for r in report.findall("object/reportitems/reportitem"):
    r.append(test)
```

I get this output:

```
<report>
    <object id="foo">
        <reportitems>
            <reportitem id="1"/>
            <reportitem id="2"/>
            <reportitem id="3"><test foo="bar"/></reportitem>
        </reportitems>
    </object>
</report>
```

Now, if I modify the code like this (using the same XML snippet):

```
report = ET.fromstring(myxml)
myElements = [ET.Element("test1"), ET.Element("test2"), ET.Element("test3")]

counter = 0
for r in report.findall("object/reportitems/reportitem"):
    r.append(myElements[counter])
    counter += 1
```

...then I get this output:

```
<report>
    <object id="foo">
        <reportitems>
            <reportitem id="1"><test1/></reportitem>
            <reportitem id="2"><test2/></reportitem>
            <reportitem id="3"><test3/></reportitem>
        </reportitems>
    </object>
</report>
```

Why can't I add the same (identical) element as a child to a number of elements that I iterate over?

Comment: What is expected output? Currently, you are not passing identical elements: `test1 != test2`.

Comment: What I expected was to be able to add the identical element as a child to each of the <reportitem> elements (with an id of 1, 2 and 3) respectively. I added the modified script which adds different child elements successfully as a (hopefully relevant?) contrast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is described in the [lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html):

> There is another important case where the behaviour of Elements in
>   lxml (in 2.0 and later) deviates from that of lists and from that of
>   the original ElementTree (prior to version 1.3 or Python 2.7/3.2):

```
>>> for child in root:
...     print(child.tag)
child0 child1 child2 child3
>>> root[0] = root[-1]  # this moves the element in lxml.etree!
>>> for child in root:
...     print(child.tag)
child3 child1 child2
```

> In this example, the last element is moved to a different position,
>   instead of being copied, i.e. it is automatically removed from its
>   previous position when it is put in a different place. In lists,
>   objects can appear in multiple positions at the same time, and the
>   above assignment would just copy the item reference into the first
>   position, so that both contain the exact same item:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> l[0] = l[-1]
>>> l
[3, 1, 2, 3]
```

> Note that in the original ElementTree, a single Element object can sit in any number of places in any number of trees,
>   which allows for the same copy operation as with lists. The obvious
>   drawback is that modifications to such an Element will apply to all
>   places where it appears in a tree, which may or may not be intended.
>   The upside of this difference is that an Element in lxml.etree always
>   has exactly one parent, which can be queried through the getparent()
>   method. This is not supported in the original ElementTree.

```
>>> root is root[0].getparent()  # lxml.etree only!
True
```

> If you want to copy an element to a different position in lxml.etree, consider
>   creating an independent deep copy using the copy module from Python's
>   standard library:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy

>>> element = etree.Element("neu")
>>> element.append( deepcopy(root[1]) )

>>> print(element[0].tag)
child1
>>> print([ c.tag for c in root ])
['child3', 'child1', 'child2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in constructor `ET.Element` its create only one node per call. You can change parent of the node, but `ET.Element` will be only one. You can create `ET.Element` multiple times in loop to avoid this problem:

```
for r in report.findall("object/reportitems/reportitem"):
    node = ET.Element("test", foo="bar")
    r.append(node)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think the OP asks *why* is that? Trying to find an actual explanation in the docs or the source code..